# Fixed position and overflow scroll in CSS

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have modal form with fixed position.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      Form header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have scrollable content in my form (div class="content"), but CSS property **overflow-y: scroll** not working correctly. Scroll bar appears but content not hidden.

**CSS:**

```
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Demo:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1w16suc/)

Comment: Please check this link it will help you  http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/ZOyGOB

Comment: Thank you, with fixed height work correct, but I want to make the content height dynamic. If content more than 100% - 50px scroll must appear

Comment: http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/ZOyGOB

Comment: .content { min-height: 30vh;   max-height: 60vh; } you can adjust the value of height

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), it works great with dynamic height of the header and content area.

Set the container to `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`, set the content to `flex: 1;` so it expands to take all the space available apart from the header.

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 2px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div style="height:2000px;">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obptdho8/)**

Comment: Thank you! Flexbox that's what I need!

Answer (score 0):

changing your `.content` class to have a fixed value of `height` instead of a percentage for `max-height` seems to correct the issue, for example:

`.content { height: 250px; }`

Comment: I know that with fixed height scroll work correct, but I need form with dynamic height content.

Answer (score 0):

Could please try this code.

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 30vh;
  max-height: 60vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      Form header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height in pixels rather than percentage  and set overflow property to auto. If you would set height to `100%` then the div will grow vertically according to content, to fix this issue you have to set height in pixels. `Overflow:auto;` will automatically provide the scroll bar as height is fixed. Like this:

```
.content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

If you need **dynamic content height** then try following code and play with it:

```
.content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height:200px;
  max-height:100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:white;
}
```

The best solution is to use flexbox. Add following properties:

```
.box
{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
} 
.content
{
flex: 1;
}
```

Remove `height:100&;` from `content class`.

Answer (score 0):

`.content` `max-height: xx%;` will be % of null (not effective at all), because **no** `height` is specified on `.box`.

You may use flex or rethink structure and centering method( many ways).

flex example use of 3 extra line of css (*see comments* /* here */ ):

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;/* here */
  flex-flow: column;/* here */
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  flex: 1;/* here */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      Form header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
      Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Flexbox that's what I need!

Answer (score 0):

hello there is an [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1w16suc/1/)

`hope this help`

Answer (score 0):

With Tailwind CSS:

```html
<div class="bg-gray-500 pt-10 ">
  Normal page content
  <div class="fixed top-0 h-full flex flex-col w-1/2  ">
    <div class="overflow-y-auto">
          <div class="h-[2000px] bg-gradient-to-b from-red-500/60 to-blue-500/60">
            Scrollable content in fixed div
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```